# android error unknown method 'getTitle'

Tags: java, android

Hello i'm testing the following code it's suppose to list all apps installed on an android powered machine.
To edit an compile it i use [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&feature=search_result)
an android java editor the problem is that AIDE always showing me an error: " unknown method 'getTitle'".
Someone can help me please?

```
public class AppListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

  private LayoutInflater mInflater;
  private List<App> mApps;

  public AppListAdapter(Context context) {
     // cache the LayoutInflater to avoid asking for a new one each time
     mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
  }

  @Override
  public int getCount() {
    return mApps.size();
  }

  @Override
  public Object getItem(int position) {
    return mApps.get(position);
  }

  @Override
  public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
  }

  @Override
  public View getView(int pos, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    AppViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
      convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.row, null);

      // creates a ViewHolder and stores a reference to the child view
      holder = new AppViewHolder();
      holder.mTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.apptitle);
      convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
      // reuse/overwrite the view passed assuming(!) that it is castable!
      holder = (AppViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.setTitle(mApps.get(pos).getTitle());

    return convertView;
  }

  public void setListItems(List<App> list) {
    mApps = list;
  }

  /**
   * A view holder which is used to reuse views inside a list.
   */
  public class AppViewHolder {

    private TextView mTitle;

    /**
     * Sets the text to be shown as the app's title
     *
     * @param title the text to be shown inside the list row
     */
     public void setTitle(String title) {
       mTitle.setText(title);
     }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably have no **getTitle()** method in your **App** class

Comment: Sorry but i'm a total newbie where can i check that?

Comment: @GwanfalAgoulou can you post your App class source code?from where did you grab this code?

Comment: I grab it from a book and i found it on this site too
http://impressive-artworx.de/2011/list-all-installed-apps/#comment-1033

Comment: @GwanfalAgoulou the code works!!, have you written all classes by AIDE?

Comment: maybe it's because of this missing part
// ...getters and setters omitted...

Sorry for the inconvenience the omitted part was included in the app.java delivered trough the zip.

Comment: i have them and i had check all files but app.java ;-)

Answer (score 0):

```
 mApps.get(pos)
```

returns you an object of type `App`

You would have to create a `getTitle` method in the `App` class.

Comment: It's not included in android?
How can i do that i just read that code from a book and i'm trying it.